# Get a large number of messages from clients using an embedded Jetty Web Server

Tags: java, server, jetty

I have a project where a server needs to be able to connect to a large number of clients and recieve observation messages from them and place them into a queue. My current rough implementation uses a very basic handler to get client requests as text:

```
public class JettyServer
{

    public JettyServer() throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(6558);
        ObservationHandler handler = new ObservationHandler();
        server.setHandler(handler);

        server.start();
        server.join();

    } 

    public class ObservationHandler extends AbstractHandler
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
        {
            String requestString = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

            // code to add requestString to thread safe queue ...

            baseRequest.setHandled(true);
        }

    }
}
```

This allows me to get client requests as text but I am not sure this is how I am supposed to do it. Is there a way to receive information in from clients not in the form of requests? Jetty seems to be very focused on server to client transactions but not vice versa. I've used jetty web sockets before but I am not sure that what I want here as the connection to clients can be intermittent. Is there a better server service or Jetty implementation to perform this with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just create a servlet that will retreive the data and process it as you wish?

Just create a class that extends HttpServlet:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
```

Then, override `doGet` or `doPost` methods like this :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.getWriter().println("<h1>"+greeting+"</h1>");
    response.getWriter().println("session=" + request.getSession(true).getId());
}
```

In your server configuration, you will also have to add you servlet to the context, according to the "path" your servlet will listen to. In the following example there are three instances of `HelloServlet`. The first listens to every path, the second only to paths beginning with "/it" and the third to paths beginning with "/fr" :

```
public class OneServletContext{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
     Server server = new Server(8080);

     ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
     context.setContextPath("/");
     server.setHandler(context);

     context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloServlet()),"/*");
     context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloServlet("Buongiorno Mondo")),"/it/*");
     context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new HelloServlet("Bonjour le Monde")),"/fr/*");

     server.start();
     server.join();
}
```

}

For further details, please have a look at https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

Comment: Thanks. Im very new to all this so sorry if it was an obvious answer. Am I right in saying that doPost intercepts all POST messages from clients (sent to the correct URL)